# Cannot remove folder from Internal Storage

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.3-jelly-bean, file-management, delete

I have a aroblem with my rooted Galaxy Nexus running Paranoid Android 4.3 (3.99). I have 2 folders in the main memory named `/rom` and `/roms` which I cannot remove nor with a file manager nor with a terminal. Can anybody help me?

Here is my console output:

```
root@maguro:/ # cd storage/sdcard0/     

root@maguro:/storage/sdcard0 # ls -al
[[many more, I am hiding the rest]]
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-01-14 20:02 rom
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2013-10-12 11:45 roms

root@maguro:/storage/sdcard0 # rm -rf rom
rm failed for rom, Permission denied

255|root@maguro:/storage/sdcard0 # rm -rf roms
rm failed for roms, Permission denied

255|root@maguro:/storage/sdcard0 #
```

Comment: I know you're running as root but....have you tried this command WITH sudo?

Comment: your syntax looks correct according to the [man page](http://ss64.com/bash/rm.html) can you try `rm -Rv ./rom` 
-v turns switches into verbose
`-v, --verbose
Explain what is being done`

Comment: Okay I found another solution: I went into TWRP and deleted them with the file manager.

Comment: Might be already too long already, but could you post your comment as an answer, if that really solved your issue? Self-answering is acceptable and even encouraged here.